# Java suddenly stops writing to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, filereader

I'm trying to write something like a text file interpreter. I decided to start with the basics and write something that dissects a string:

```
public static void dataImport() throws IOException {

BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\(my name)\\Desktop\\javaWrite.txt"));
ArrayList<String> orderLine = new ArrayList<>();

String line = null;
String endResult = "";
String currentChar = null;

while((line = dataReader.readLine()) != null) {        
        for(int character = 0; character < line.length(); character++) {                
            currentChar = line.substring(character, character+1);                                
            if(currentChar.equals("|")) {                    
                for(String singleChar : orderLine) {                        
                    endResult += singleChar;
                }                    
                fileThings.add(endResult);                    
                endResult = "";
                orderLine.clear();                    
            }else{                    
                orderLine.add(currentChar);
            }                
        }            
}                
dataReader.close();
}
```

The text file it's reading from has "Hello|world!" writen.

The code outputs "Hello", nothing else. When I had it output the currentChar variable inside the else, it just continued reading the whole sentense. So all evidence leads to ArrayList orderLine being the problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised that the output isn't `world!` instead because once the `|` is encountered, the `ArrayList` is cleared.

Comment: @MattCremeens But it was added to `fileThings` (whatever that is), and it is there that `world!` is missing.

Comment: @Andreas, ah, I understand now. I was thinking that the OP was printing the contents of `orderLine`.

Comment: have you tried javascript? you can do this easily in jQuery

Comment: @Andreas Whoops, missed something when copying. fileThings is just another ArrayList of String variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code appends data to the array list only when it sees the | character in the input data. Your input data contains only one | character. Therefore, you get only one line in the output ArrayList.

Comment: I'm confused. It appears to me that `orderLine` is added to only when the `|` isn't encountered, as it is in the `else` clause. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: The OP didn't show the part of their code that displays the output, and I assumed the code outputs the contents of the fileThings list.

Comment: I see now. Yes, you're right: the OP didn't say what they were outputting, which added to my confusion.

Comment: @yole Ah, my bad. It just uses a for-each loop in main to output filleThings

Answer (score 0):

As @yole already said in another answer, you only call `fileThings.add()` when you see a `|`, and there is no `|` at the end of the line.

But, your code has a few performance issues, worst being the `String += String` construct. VERY bad for performance, given that the compiler converts that into:

```
endResult = new StringBuilder().append(endResult).append(singleChar).toString();
```

And that occurs in a loop. Yikes!

Besides, why use `String currentChar = line.substring(character, character+1)` when you really want `char currentChar = line.charAt(character)`?

For what you're doing, just split on `|`. Since the `split()` method takes a regular expression, and `|` has special meaning, it has to be escaped, and you should use try-with-resources:

```
try (BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\(my name)\\Desktop\\javaWrite.txt"))) {
    for (String line; (line = dataReader.readLine()) != null; ) {
        for (String endResult : line.split("\\|") {
            fileThings.add(endResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I should have known my code wasn't perfect (mainly because I only started Java a moth ago, and haven't tried anything too advanced).                                                                                          NetBeans told me to use try-with-resources too, but I don't know how that works yet. In fact, the code to read the file line by line is code I copied from the internet.                                                                                                                                                           But things like the split, I will look into